# Grep the first line from each contiguous group of matching lines

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a data file which looks like this:

```
a separator
interesting line 1
interesting line 2
a comment
interesting line 3
interesting line 4
interesting line 5
a non interesting line
some other data
interesting line 6
.
.
.
```

and I would like to extract the first `interesting line` from each contiguous group, no matter how many lines are in the group is or how many extra lines separate the groups.

For the test input above the output would be:

```
interesting line 1
interesting line 3
interesting line 6
```

I could easily do this in python by having a state variable that triggers when I match a line, and resets when I encounter a non-matching line, but what about a one-line shell script? Is there a not-too-obscure way to do this?

Comment: It's not clear for me if your problem is about bash or about the (multiline) regex to give to grep?

Comment: @syme if grep is powerful enough to achieve this, it would be a perfectly fine solution. I do not need pure bash, the unix ecosystem is ok.

Comment: I just want to say that this question looks perfectly clear to me and I would not close it.

Comment: I was writing an answer that I can no longer post:
`grep -Pzo '([^\n]*interesting line[^\n]*data[^\n]*\n)+' file | while IFS='' read -d '' -r match; do head -n1 <<< "$match"; done`. For short: grep with greedy regex with NUL separated matches + while reading each match to print only their first line.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk thank you for your comment, it may have been a little less clear before editing, but when the downvoting and closing process starts it is very hard to veer it away.

Comment: @syme I voted to reopen, if it will ever get done I would be happy to upvote your answer. In the meanwhile I can only say thank you.

Comment: I agree with @ArkadiuszDrabczyk. The only thing that was not clear for me has been answered & the clarity has already been improved in the question (which is why I was writing my answer, better explained than what I had to post in comment).

Comment: Another possible answer if the question gets reopened: `awk '/^interesting/ {if (NR>ingroup) print; ingroup=NR+1}'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep with a greedy regex, then print the first line of every match with :

```
grep -Pzo '([^\n]*interesting line[^\n](\n|$))+' file |
  while IFS='' read -d '' -r match
  do
    head -n1 <<< "$match"
  done
```

`grep` parameters:

- `-P` : Use Perl Compatible regular expression (instead of the default basic regular expression) for the \n in the regex.
- `-z` : Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte. An ASCII NUL character will separate each match, allowing us to reliably separate the matches.
- the regex `([^\n]*blablabla[^\n]*(\n|$))+` will match each group of contiguous lines containing blablabla.

In the while condition command, the IFS is emptied for the `read`. Otherwise, with the default IFS, the last newline character of each match would be eaten by `read` (that might not be a problem). It's a good practice to always clear IFS in "while read" to get the text in the variable exactly as it is read (leading spaces are also easily eaten up).

`read` parameters:

- `-d ''` : Use the empty string as delimiter (= the ASCII NUL character). This is equivalent to `-d $'\0'` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/61029/283498).
- `-r` : don't interpret any backslash in the lines (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192786/283498).
- `match` : just a variable name I chose, which is used in the body of the loop.

And in the body of the loop: `head -n1 <<< "$match"` prints only the first line of the current match (the command `head` with `-n 1` prints the first 1 line of its input). Side note: `<<<` is a bashism ; the command is equivalent to `echo "$match" | head -n1`.